# 3 dimension prediction limit in R

Tags: r, optimization, limits

Let a data set with 3 variables (here Normal and independent but they can be correlated)

```
data = data.frame(x1 = rnorm(10000),
x2 = rnorm(10000),
x3 = rnorm(10000))
```

I would like to get the narrowest range for x1, x2 and x3 such that 95% of the observation fall within all three ranges.

So far I have the code below.

```
is.between <- function(x, a, b){
    x <= max(c(a, b)) & x >= min(c(a, b))
  }   
getlims <- function(lims, x1, x2, x3){
      abs(mean(
        is.between(x1, lims[1], lims[2]) & 
          is.between(x2, lims[3], lims[4]) & 
          is.between(x3, lims[5], lims[6]) 
      ) - 0.95) 
    }

optim(initial_values, getlims, x1=x1,x2=x2,x3=x3)
```

Where lims[1,2] is the range for x1, lims[3,4] is the range for x2 and lims[5,6] is the range for x3.

It provides limits that contain 95% of my observation, but doesn't guarantee that it will be the smaller volume lims[1,2]*lims[3,4]*lims[5,6].

Comment: Could you define 'volume' as well?

Comment: on a 3-dimensional plot (x1,x2,x3), setting limits on each variable provides a rectangular prism. The smallest volume for this prism is the smallest value for the product of the limits ranges.

Comment: If `x1,x2,x3` are vectors, then you need to calculate the variable: `x1(x)x2(dot)x3`  where `(x)` is the cross product and `(dot)` the inner product (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product)

Comment: x1, x2 and x3 are random variables.
If lims[1,2] are limits for x1; lims[3,4] are limits for x2; and lims[5,6] are limit for x3, optimizing the function getlims above gives me what I want: values of lims that result in a rectangle prism containing 95% of the values.

I'm looking for a way to lower the volume of this rectangle prism. That is, find the smaller value of (lims[2]-lims[1])*(lims[4]-lims[3])*(lims[6]-lims[5]) to ensure 95% coverage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is actually a problem in discrete optimization. It was given in three dimensions, I have reformulated it in two dimensions to have a better visualization, it can be immediately extended to more dimensions.

Let us try to solve it as a nonlinear optimization problem with constraints.

```
set.seed(1009)
N <- 1000
x <- rnorm(N); y <- rnorm(N)
```

The 0.05 and 0.95 quantiles of these coordinates will also be needed.

```
q1 <- quantile(x, 0.05); q2 <- quantile(x, 0.95)
q3 <- quantile(y, 0.05); q4 <- quantile(y, 0.95)
```

We define two functions, `fmin` the function that is to be minimized, and `fbnd` the function that defines the constraints. That is, we require `fbnd(x) >= 0`, in this way expressing that at least 95% of the points lie inside the rectangle.

```
fmin <- function(p) (p[2]-p[1]) * (p[4]-p[3])
fbnd <- function(p) {
    c(0.05 - sum(x < p[1] | x > p[2] | y < p[3] | y > p[4]) / N,
      q1 - p[1], p[2] - q2,
      q3 - p[3], p[4] - q4 )
}
```

As starting point we can take the ranges of x- and y-coordinates.

```
start <- c(range(x), range(y))
```

The optimization solver has to minimize a function with nonlinear constraints. The `auglag` routine in package *nloptr* is a candidate solver.

```
S <- nloptr::auglag(start, fn=fmin, hin=fbnd)
S$par; S$value
# [1] -2.301263  2.308038 -2.079166  2.130744
# [1] 19.40474
```

We can improve the solution by moving the rectangle boundaries to the next upper or lower x- resp. y-coordinate. This is a necessary step as the objective function is locally constant.

```
r <- S$par
r[1] <- min(x[x >= r[1]]); r[2] <- max(x[x <= r[2]])
r[3] <- min(y[y >= r[3]]); r[4] <- max(y[y <= r[4]])
r
# [1] -2.299467  2.281395 -2.079166  2.127260
```

We can see, 50 points lie outside the rectangle and the area is 19.26905.

```
(r[2]-r[1]) * (r[4]-r[3])                          # 19.26905
sum(x < r[1] | x > r[2] | y < r[3] | y > r[4])     # 50
```

The solution could still be a local minimum. Fortunately, the objective function is also locally monotone, so this will normally not happen. Of course, one could verify the solution by applying a global solver.

Comment: Indeed the value is still a local minimum. I tried your code and here is a simple example:

S <- nloptr::auglag(start*1.1, fn=fmin, hin=fbnd);
S$value;
S <- nloptr::auglag(start*1.1, fn=fmin, hin=fbnd);
S$value;

It doesn't return the same value.

Comment: Actually, with `start*1.1` and the improvement as above we get 19.26253 again. You may try `start*0.95` or similar to end up with values like 19.3725 or 19.28947. That's why I said this is a *discrete* optimization problem and cannot be solved reliably with a continuous optimization solver.

Comment: Still you are right and this is only a local minimum. The true minimum for this example is `19.16451`, found doing an exhaustive search. Your voting my answer as a solution may have been a bit premature. Take it back if you like.

I got interested in solving this as a discrete optimization problem and asked on [Stackoverflow](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/27040/a-95-minimal-rectangle-problem). You can find an possible algorithm there, but certainly there is no R implementation, and probably it would be much too slow.